# Structures - Initializing and Writing to File

Tags: c#, c++

I'm converting some code from C++ to C# as a method to learn C#. In my C++ code I have

```
struct ChArray{
    char ch[8];
};

bool operator < (const ChArray& arrA, const ChArray& arrB);
```

In my C++, I can do things like:

```
map<ChArray, double>::iterator s;
for(s = settings.begin(); s != settings.end(); s++){
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&s->first), sizeof(ChArray));
}
```

The question is what is necessary to accomplish the same things in C#?

Not the map part (I know to use Dictionary), but rather, how do I create a set sized structure that can be easily written to and read from a file?

I've tried several combinations, all result in some error which seems like it would cause a problem later on when writing.

For instance, with a structure, I can't define the default size, which means I have to use new to dynamically allocate memory, which means (to me as a C++ programmer) that there would be no accurate way to guarantee the size of the structure when the file is being read, because the dynamic allocation could have been anything when the structure was initialized.

Maybe I'm just not aware of some c# power that would clear up this mess.

Comment: Just so I understand your requriements correctly: you just want to write 8 bytes to a binary file? So `out.write(s->first.ch, sizeof(s->first.ch))` would also do the trick correct?

Comment: @MikeMB, Would that work? It's viable, but if I'm having to dynamically allocate, wouldn't I jut get the size of a pointer, not the size of how many characters there are? But also, we're back to the guarantee the size with one number thing again as well.

Comment: As ch is a fixed size array, yes this works as long as the size of char is one byte - im not sure if this is defined in the standard. The following would probably be more robust: `out.write(s->first.ch, sizeof(s->first.ch)/sizeof(s->first.ch[0]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# e.g. provides `BinaryReader` and `BinaryWriter` that allowes you to read and write Byte arrays from and to a file.

I believe your problem is, that you try to convert c++ to c# code on too low a level, where systemIO is concerned

EDIT: Maybe I missunderstand you, but If you want to directly translate your c++ code into c# code what's wrong with using the following struct:

```
class Ch8Array
{
    public byte[] ch = new byte[8];
}
```

and read/write via:

```
Ch8Array arr = new Ch8Array();

using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open("test", FileMode.Open))) {
    reader.Read(arr.ch, 0, arr.ch.Length);
} 

using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open("test2", FileMode.Create))) {
    writer.Write(arr.ch);
}
```

(for sake of clarity I omitted the map part)

Comment: Well, doesn't C++ have the same thing? But the question is, if I allocate 9 bits for my structure for one object, and 7 for another object, then how I do know to read that in at those sizes? Yes, I can use constants, but it come down to, with C++ one number dictates both read and write size. C# could differ because the number can exist in more than one place.

Comment: Again, if the framework is just different and it just KNOWS, great. (I'm pretty sure it doesn't) But with a potential variable like that, it seems dangerous. I suppose I could use a constructor, but then I'm growing my structure size, which isn't a lot, but it seems like bad coding to do that.

Comment: What 's your target ? You want to write ChArray's data to file & read from file later , right? 
So in C# , you can write a object to file & read from file . You have to implement ISerializable & override 2 method to do this.

Comment: Well, I don't like it, because the C++ version is so much easier, but oh well. Since I have to do that, I just created a full class complete with constructor, implicit overload, and ToString overload so I can just use each class as a variable. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Well, in the end it highly depends on what you want to do with it in. C# often allows you to write the same functionality with less code, because it has a much bigger Library support. However, this only helps, if you use the libraries from the beginning and not if you try to translate c++ code line by line (which is more or less what I've done in my answer)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you try to work at a higher level in C#. Especially if you want to get to know the language. C# trades of some low-level capabilities for vastly increased productivity. Embrace that.

What you want is directly translatable to C# using [Fixed Size Buffers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zycewsya.aspx). Alternatively, you could use the `StructLayoutAttribute` to set a fixed size for a struct and control member layout. C# supports unsafe code quite well. This is often used for interop with native APIs.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use class ChArray instead of structure ChArray
And in your default contructor you can allocate a array of char with size = 8.